# Kotlin Delegate goes wrong

Tags: kotlin

If i am using it this way it will always throw NoSuchElementException, Where goes wrong?

```
val sessionMap: ConcurrentHashMap<String, Session> by object : ConcurrentHashMap<String, WebSocketSession>() {
    override fun put(key: String, value: Session): Session? {
        ........
        return super.put(key, value)
    }
}
```

the exception

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: Key sessionMap is missing in the map.
```

is that the object does not have a type?

Comment: How are you using `sessionMap`?

Comment: What do you try to achieve with this code? This is not really how you use `by map`. It tries to acquire `sessionMap` by asking the anonymous map for its `sessionMap` key. Do you mean `=` instead of `by`?

Comment: @enzo I think it does not matter with how i am using it, I deleted all other lines except the return statement and it also failed. if i use plain Map() object, everything is fine

Comment: base on the original functionality, when new element are up, do  more thing. isn't the actually object doing thing is the anonymous object? @broot

Comment: I have problems understanding the last sentence. I think you got right the anonymous object part. The problem is that you delegated to it (`by`) instead of just assigning it (`=`).

Answer (score 1):

If you just mean to set the property to a `ConcurrentHashMap`, but override some of its methods then you don't really need delegation and you should use `=` instead of `by`. You also have to use either `Session` or `WebSocketSession` consistently.

```kotlin
val sessionMap = object : ConcurrentHashMap<String, Session>() {
    override fun put(key: String, value: Session): Session? {
        ........
        return super.put(key, value)
    }
}
```